# Save custom post type to external database

Tags: custom-post-types, database, wpdb

I'm creating an advertising portal for a small network using a custom post type. In order to prevent WordPress database corruption or unauthorized access to user information, I need to keep data separated from the advertising app by duplicating custom post type data to an external database when creating and updating an ad post. I'm using the `save_post` hook to handle when the function should run, and `wp_insert_post()` to push all post data into the database. What I want to happen is that the post will save in the WordPress database by default, and also save to an external database using my plugin function.

The issue I can't figure out is how to tell `wp_insert_post()` to use the external database instead of the `global $wpdb` variable it uses by default, as outlined in WP code reference.

How can I use a custom database with `wp_insert_post`? Or is there a better method?

My function, based on WordPress codex and Stack Exchange examples:

```
// Function to push data on update
function my_data_push ($post_id) {
    // Check for custom post type
    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'ads'):
        // Set up database connection to external ads storage database
        $push_to_db = new wpdb('username','password','database','host');
        // Insert post data in external database
            wp_insert_post($post_id, $wp_error = true);
    endif;
}
// Add function to post save hook
add_action('save_post', 'my_data_push');
```

Comment: If it is not in the posts table it is not a CPT. If you need to write to external DB, just write to it however you which.

Comment: Haven't heared yet of any WP solution to connect to another data base. However, while reading your question, [Pods framework](http://pods.io/docs/learn/what-are-advanced-content-types/) came to my mind. Pods supports so called Advanced Content Types, which can be stored in separate db tables rather than in wp_posts. Question is, if these tables could in another data base. You may ask their friendly staff in their Slack channel.

Comment: The posts are in the posts table. I'm trying to create a second operation on save that will also save the post data to an external database. Using the `wpdb()` function, it is possible to connect to another database. The question is how to easily write the complete post data to the external db.

Comment: I updated the post for clarity. What I want to happen are two things: 1. Save the post normally in the WordPress database. 2. Store the same information in an external database. The plugin function above should handle #2.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this question for over a month now - i do not think wordpress is very good for any site that has a secure external DB or for anyone who does not want to store customer data in the main wordpress database, which is strange as that seems like a highly valued function.

At any rate i came across this code during my research that may help you - it is a global variable for a external DB... according to the author it is usable in the same way as $wpdb global variable is used.

If you want the author's full blurb on it go here https://bavotasan.com/2011/access-another-database-in-wordpress/

The code is:
$newdb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);
$newdb->show_errors();

Hopefully it is of some use to you...

Answer (score 0):

**wp_insert_post** only works **for wordpress own database.**

You need to write a custom query using the $wpdb class.

The `$wpdb` class allows you to interact with multiple databases in WordPress.

```
global $wpdb;

// Define the database credentials for the other database
$other_db_name = 'other_database_name';
$other_db_user = 'other_database_user';
$other_db_password = 'other_database_password';
$other_db_host = 'other_database_host';

// Connect to the other database
$other_db = new wpdb($other_db_user, $other_db_password, $other_db_name, $other_db_host);

// Define the tables to access
$posts_table = $other_db->prefix . 'posts'; 

// Query the data
$insert = $other_db->insert().
```

Use `$wpdb->insert()`.

```
$other_db->insert($posts_table, array(
    'post_title' => 'title',
    'post_name' => 'post-slug', // ... and so on
));
```